# Laravel - Array Output Issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to take an output from a db, search pass it over from a controller using compact, and then pass it to a custom blade helper.

When I pass over the db details I get a value of said users id and this can be displayed using

```
@foreach($SelectUser as $key => $UserArray)

     {{$UserArray->user_id}}

 @endforeach
```

I will get an output as expected of a users id e.g. 1.

When I try to combine this with my helper to change the value in to a readable username it dose not seam to output a value for the helper class to convert to a readable username.

```
    @foreach($selectUseras $key => $UserArray)

     @FindUsername($UserArray->user_id)

 @endforeach
```

helper class is

```
    public function boot()
{
 
    //A Helper to translate a user id number in to a readable username 

    Blade::directive('FindUsername', function ($id) {

        // Request infomation from the db useing eloquent
        $username = User::where('id', $id)
                    ->pluck('username');

        //Results to an array
        $arr = $username->toArray();

        //Filter through array results
        $i = implode(" ",$arr);

        return $i;
    
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blade directive should return not real value, but some php-code. You should change your directive to:

```
//Filter through array results
$i = implode(" ",$arr);

// return php-code which echo'es you value
return "<?php echo $i;?>";
```

Comment: Thanks I agree their should be some php code it was their i had taken it out while just trying fixes and not put it back. but still it had no value passed.

Comment: Did you debug directive's code? What if you return a value like `echo "Something"` instead of `$i`? Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the values, not return. 
When blade file will be compiled and blade directive will be resolved, then it will only show the printed values like a php file does,

> for ex: in a php file if you write $i = 1;, then it will not shown when it will be compiled in browser, it will only shows when you do `echo $i`;

So you need to return this

```
return "<?php echo $i;?>";
```

> Don't forget to run `php artisan view:clear`, you need to clear your compiled view before updating the directive.

Comment: Thanks I agree their should be some php code it was their i had taken it out while just trying fixes and not put it back. but still it had no value passed. as it works without the return "<?php echo $i;?>";

Comment: @ItsLewis Did you run this command which will delete the cached views. `php artisan view:clear`, it may be the one of the reason, because views are already cached and it is not taking this new directive ?